# Flask sqlalchemy Marshmallow deserialize many to many 'dict' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

I'm trying to user marshmallow's .load() method to deserialize a json object on a POST request. But I keep running into this error `'dict' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'` Users and Roles has a many to many relationship. .dump() on the schema works fine, but .load() can save all the other fields except the multiple roles. I'm trying to pass this in my json body.

```
{
    "last_name": "Fin",
    "roles": [{"id": 3, "role": "admin"}],
    "email": "test3@test.com",
    "first_name": "Al",
    "access_id": "ec1235",
    "password": "1234567"
}
```

My user and Role models

```
user_role = db.Table('user_role',
                 db.Column('user_id', db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                 db.Column('role_id', db.ForeignKey('role.id')),
                 db.Column('properties', JSONType),
                 )

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    access_id = db.Column(db.String(6), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(EmailType, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=user_role, backref='user', cascade="all")

class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

My Schema

```
class RoleSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "role")
        model = Role

class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    roles = ma.Nested(RoleSchema, many=True)

    class Meta:
        load_instance = True
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "access_id", "email", "roles, "password")
        model = User
```

Post request

```
    def post(self):
        try:
            body = request.get_json()
            user = user_schema.load(body)
            user.hash_password()
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return {'id': str(user.id)}, 200
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("")
```